# Is UIDevice multitaskingSupported checking necessary nowadays?

Tags: ios, multitasking, uidevice

I checked [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitasking_(iOS)) and got to know that from the 3rd-generation iOS device (iPod touch 3 and iPhone 3GS I guess), the multitasking was supported.

So that means **all the iOS device nowadays are multitasking supporting** since the deployment target is 4.3. And the devices running that version of iOS are newer than "the 3rd-generation".

So **no need to check** `[UIDevice currentDevice].multitaskingSupported` , am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The last iPhone that didn't support multitasking was the iPhone 3G.

And since new apps these days shouldn't support anything older than iOS 7 (maybe nut rarely, iOS 6), there is no reason to check for multitasking.

And Apple only accepts apps that support iOS 4.3 or later. Any device that didn't support multitasking could never be updated to 4.3.

Any device a modern app will be running on these days will support multitasking.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.